# Query to determine whether a certain compound primary key has been used?

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have a mysql table with a compound primary key. The table definition looks like(some column omitted):

```
CREATE TABLE `wasteitem` (
  `categoryid` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `classid` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `LIflag` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`categoryid`,`classid`)
);
```

And I want to determine if *any* of known keys have been used.
If the table have only a simple primary key I can use query like this:

```
select categoryid from wasteitem where categoryid in ('key1','key2','key3','key4')
```

Things to be concerned:

- The primary key is a compound key.
- The known keys in the list might be very long.
- This table is very big(26GB)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the keys you're interested in in another (temporary) table, and join.

Comment: It seems this is the only choice I can have. Is there any better solution ?

Comment: Better? It depends on your requirements. Faster? Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

use it, to look for keys

```
DESCRIBE wasteitem
```

that would be something similar:

```
mysql> describe wasteitem;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| categoryid | char(4) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| classid    | char(4) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| LIflag     | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```